# Force iPhone keyboard to appear over Safari window when I make an input visible

Tags: javascript, ios

This may be simply impossible, judging from the many comments on this topic in StackOverflow from several years ago.  However, in case I am missing something, here's the situation:

I have an html canvas element.  When the user taps it, I make an input element visible. Ideally, the input gets the focus and on a mobile device, the native keyboard pops up.

And that's what happens on an Android device.  However, when an iPhone user on Safari taps the canvas, the input appears but it doesn't get the focus and the native keyboard does not appear.  The user has to tap the input element for the native keyboard to show up.

Does anyone have a way to make the keyboard show up on an iPhone without that last extra tap?

Here is a test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" style="width:100px;height:100px;position:relative;background-color:blue"></div>
    <div id="holder">
        <form>
            <input id="in">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#holder").hide();
    $("#box").mousedown(function() {
        $("#holder").show({complete:function() {$("#in").focus();}});
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a combination of strategies that works.  Not sure why, but if I handle the tap in 'touchstart' instead of 'mousedown,' and add an extra call to 'focus,' the IOS device awards me focus and native keyboard:

```
$("#box").on("touchstart", function(e) {
    $("#holder").show({complete:function() {$("#in").focus();}});
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#in").focus();
});
```